# HTML And Discord Python - Javascript parse

Tags: javascript, html, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to parse a bot latency? Like, for a uptime monitoring and a latency monitoring example, DIscord API Latency, I wan't it to record the uptime, latency, command used, total members or total server.

Comment: This question is kind of vague—do you want to know how to access your bot's uptime, latency, etc. in your code? Or are you trying to send this data to a website?

Comment: @wgumenyuk both of them, i already made a html template (a bad one) for the bot uptime, ping, command used, users, total guilds when im on my phone (I Don't have access to my bot server when im on my phone)

Comment: That is certainly possible. Within your code, you can access for example `bot.latency` (read more in the [official docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bot#client)). Then you'll only need a way to send that data directly to your webpage, you can use websockets for this.

Comment: Websocket from the Discord.Py API DIrectly or use Another API? @wgumenyuk

Comment: For that you would need to use your own API. Discord.py's websockets are only for connecting to Discord's bot API.

Comment: @wgumenyuk [is this api good?](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: It'll do the job. If you have further questions, let's move this discussion to chat.

Comment: @wgumenyuk i have a short question, how can i add the websocket that sends the data from my main bot code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223396/discussion-between-wgumenyuk-and-raphiel).